# R Markdown Stargazer – Fitting Regression Tables onto a single sheet when knitting to PDF

Tags: r, r-markdown, stargazer

If I have a super long regression table from Stargazer that I'm knitting to a pdf, how can I fit the regression table onto the page (eg. scaling the table, rotating the table)? I am just completely lost and have searched through markdown code a lot.

Comment: How long exactly? Is it a A4 page? Can you just drop some unimportant variables (omit print)? If you really like to show a 100 variable coefficients, you might choose a column-wise output.